# Scroll for disabled components in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, textarea, scroll

I have a textarea with enabled scrollbar. And here is what i want - when textarea is disabled, scroll becomes disabled also. And i want it to remain scrollable. How can i achieve this?

Comment: What characteristics about the Disabled state do you want that aren't present in the IsReadOnly state?

Comment: I'm using custom text area and there are multiple styles for it. I just don't want to clone them. Isn't there a workaround?

Comment: BTW: what if I have different situation. For example I have lots of nested controls in the panel and I want to disable all of them, but leave scrolls enabled. Basically, I'm setting IsEnabled property of the root element (panel) to false using binding. But this disables scroll as well. Any ideas (except adding IsEnabled to each control instead)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to make readonly.
set ReadOnly =true

Comment: then place your text control in panel control with some max heigt and width

Comment: In the end, I wrapped control with ScrollViewer.